# In react-native-share on ios we need to know why share options pop up screens getting dismissed immediately?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

```
composeEmail = async () => {
        const file = await this.downloadCsv();
        const res = await RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(file.path);
        if (res) {
            const data = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(file.path, 'base64');
            console.log("encoded data", data)
            if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
                const shareOptions = {
                    social: Share.Social.EMAIL,
                    subject: '',
                    filename: file.filename.split(".")[0],
                    saveToFiles: file.path,
                    url: file.path,
                    type: 'csv',
                    failOnCancel: true,
                    
                }
                try {
                    const ShareResponse = await Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Error:', error)
                }
            }
```

In that when we click on share button pop up the share screen but dismissed immediately.for that we also use Share.open(ShareOptions) but same result found.